# Make template page wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to create a new template for my pages in wordpress. How should i process. I already create a new php file in my theme.

It will allow me to redesign my page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create `myTemplate.php` in your theme directory `(./wp-content/yourTheme)`. And then you can copy/paste and then modify the code of your tempalte, or just add

```
<?php /* Template Name: Page Template Name */ get_header(); ?>
```

in the top of your file.